# SSH from Windows 10 to Manjaro Linux using its hostname

Tags: linux, windows, ssh, hostname

I am using PuTTY to connect to a Lunix machine on local network via ssh and it works fine if I specify the IP address. However I cannot do it using the machine's host name.

It seems that Windows machine doesn't have the right info for that but it works fine on Mac OS and Blink (iPad ssh client). I didn't have to explicitly specify hostname on the client machines and I do not want to do it on Windows because the Linux server address is not static.

I am running Manjaro Minimal OS on Raspberry Pi as a Linux server.

Comment: Is it only PuTTY that you have tested this with? Maybe try ping hostname or something similar in Windows?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User. See https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely the lack of mDNS resolver in Windows, though I believe that is slowly improving.

The following Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23624525/504554) and answer implies that it depends which APIs the app making the request is using and possibly if it's 64bit vs 32bit